# Please make the login bar smaller

Tags: discussion, feature-request, anonymous-user

When I'm using stackoverflow on a computer which I'm not logged into, this is my view:

[image]

While this might be great for visitor -> user conversion numbers, it's pretty horrendous UI for doing what I'm here for - getting my question answered.

Normally, when logged in, I see the question body - or at least part of it. For me, this is critical to knowing if I'm on the right page - I want to make sure that I'm getting the answers to the same questions that I have - not a very similar question.

Now, I have to scroll down to see anything more than the banner and a large advert...

Comment: And you can't just log in why?

Comment: @StephenLeppik I'm on a public computer.